# Does this show the signal strength/quality from GSM modems? why does it print 8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gsm, modem

Im trying to read the signal strength/quality from gsm modems, so i used this AT+CSQ command.

```
from time import sleep
import serial
from curses import ascii

ser = serial.Serial()

 
ser.port = "COM10"

ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.open()

print(ser.write('AT+CSQ=?'.encode("ascii")))
```

Answer (score 1):

`ser.write` returns the number of bytes written (on the port).
(https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write)

You need to call ser.read afterward to read the answear.
Something like :

```
from time import sleep
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()

ser.port = "COM10"

ser.baudrate = 9600

ser.open()
try:
    res_write = ser.write('AT+CSQ=?'.encode("ascii"))
    sleep(0.01)
    
    res_read = b""
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        res_read += ser.read(1)
        
finally : # ensure you close the use of the port in case of crash
    ser.close()
    
print(res_read.decode("ascii"))
```

Comment: it displayed the RSSI one time, it prints/displays blank now

Comment: You might want to try to increase the sleep time or replace the while ser.inWaiting() > 0: res_read += ser.read(1) by res_read += ser.read(30) (and add some print if needed for debugging). I am afraid you will have to test.